# PyYAML loading YAML 1.1 with duplicate keys

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to use PyYAML to load YAML 1.1 files (they are not tagged as such but they have the octal integer values *0123* instead of *0o123*).

I don't know how these files were generated, but one of the problems is that some of these files have duplicate keys, like:

```
xxx:
   aaa: 011
   bbb: 012
   ccc: 013
   aaa: 014
```

I am using `yaml.safe_load()` to load those files.

From reading the YAML documentation, section 10.2, I expected to get a warning and that `aaa` will have the value 9:

> It is an error for two equal keys to appear in the same mapping node.
>        In such a case the YAML processor may continue, ignoring the second 
>        key: value pair and issuing an appropriate warning.

But I get no warning and the value is 12.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to get PyYAML to select the first value for the key?

I looked at a few libraries for other languages, to clean this up before further processing but those either did throw an error, or continued with the second value.

There are many files, often with the duplicates nested much deeper. They can have complex structures between the keys, and the duplicate keys also not being unique to the mapping they occur in, which is valid. Using *awk* to fix this is not going to work these files. And too many to fix by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that is a bug in PyYAML. The offending code is [here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib3/yaml/constructor.py#L118):

```
def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
    if not isinstance(node, MappingNode):
        raise ConstructorError(None, None,
                "expected a mapping node, but found %s" % node.id,
                node.start_mark)
    mapping = {}
    for key_node, value_node in node.value:
        key = self.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
        if not isinstance(key, collections.Hashable):
            raise ConstructorError("while constructing a mapping", node.start_mark,
                    "found unhashable key", key_node.start_mark)
        value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
        mapping[key] = value
    return mapping
```

It is clear that no checks are done whether the key exists. You would have to subclass the `Constructor` to make one that has `construct_mapping()` with an included check:

```
        if key in mapping:
             warnings.warn(somewarning)
        else:
            mapping[key] = value
```

And then create a `Loader` using that `Constructor`.

It might be simpler to use `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author
of that package). It correctly loads this, assuming you disable the `DuplicateKeyError`,
and explicitly set YAML 1.1 as the input format:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_file = Path('xx.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.version = (1, 1)
yaml.indent(mapping=3, sequence=2, offset=0)
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_file)
assert data['xxx']['aaa'] == 9
yaml_out = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml_out.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

This gives:

```
xxx:
  aaa: 9
  bbb: 10
  ccc: 11
```

Your octals will be converted to decimals (normally that info is
preserved, but not when loading legacy YAML 1.1). PyYAML will always do that.

Comment: I had seen ruamel,yaml but it being a 1.2 parser, I assumed it would not handle octals etc correctly. Should I file a bug report

Comment: I would not bother with a bug report or PR, the chance that it gets "lost" the next time PyYAML changes where the bugs and repository get hosted is bigger than that the issue will be resolved.